# Running a perl script in python and storing the output in a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to run

```
script.pl < input > output
```

In python. I tried this:

```
subprocess.check_call(["script.pl","<","input",">","output"])
```

Which I guess is not the proper way to do it. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `os.system("script.pl < input > output")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to execute the shell command

```
script.pl < input > output             # 0 args, redirects stdin and stdout
```

but you are executing the shell command

```
script.pl "<" input ">" output         # 4 args, and no redirections
```

If you want to run a shell command, you'll need to run a shell.

```
subprocess.check_call(["/bin/sh", "-c", "script.pl < input > output"])
  -or-
subprocess.check_call("script.pl < input > output", shell=True)
```

It would be best if you avoided running a shell at all.

```
in_fh  = open('input', 'r')
out_fh = open('output', 'w')
subprocess.check_call("script.pl", stdin=in_fh, stdout=out_fh)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the in_fh and out_fh approach and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple,

```
import os
os.system("script.pl < input > output")
```